# How to disable all file uploads to a server?

Tags: php, apache, security

Is there a way, through `php.ini` or `.htaccess` to disable all file uploads to a server?

The only catch is, I want to have one folder (example an admin folder) to still have access to upload.

I am thinking along the lines of when you disable `eval` and `exec`.

This question stems from the fact that I have seen sites infected with malware, which are located in all random spots through the server - a recent example I have seen is something similar to:

```
eval(gzinflate(base64_decode("HZ3fdsfHjtfvdqlkdsfabf5Y7OAQfMCRc9YKaYc5o0mHOmmJ6+ .... ));
```

Located in a file called `stp.php` on a server. My thinking is that if the sites users need no access to upload files (which they don't), then it should be simply disabled.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.file-uploads

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. In your php.ini file set `file_uploads=Off` as described [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.file-uploads).
This will disable all file uploads through HTTP.