# Unable to get file upload permissions for PHP file manager

Tags: php, apache, permissions

My site is on a shared hosting. I've been using FTP and PHP File Manager to upload and delete files. Recently I've found a file I couldn't delete due to permissions, neither in PHPFM nor in FTP. So I've used DirectAdmin (the only option for my plan) to reset all permissions. Then I set all permissions for all files in public_html and subfolders to 777 recursively. I know only that it allows me to do more than any other permission variant.

Now the site is running in a static way, I can open PHP File Manager and it has no permission to upload files.  I can upload files in DirectAdmin, however, but that feels unsafe. PHP File Manager reads: 'I/O error'. The directories look like this:

[image]

What do 1422 and 1420 mean? What can I do to upload files again? Thank you for the help.

Comment: 1422 is your linux user_id and 1420 group_id.

Comment: setting 777 and using a file manager script in the server is quite a serious risk, especially if a folder permission is set as 777... where is your php file manager located? is it able to access that folder with the files to add/modify/delete from where it is residing?

Comment: @Hasse Björk, thank you! So does the fact that 1422 != 1420 mean I'm not allowed to do something?

Comment: @Aaron Gong Thank you. The PHP file manager is in public_html together with everything else. The site is relatively small and it runs on my php page generator which is rather simple (head + body + foot + timestamp). The file manager sees everything and can even create folders, but upload doesn't work.

Comment: 1422 and 1420 are the owner and group ids, most likely they are not the root user. If you set everything to 777 (including folders) usually those ids do not matter... It could also be a setting on php.ini to disallow upload input, your host may have changed it...

Comment: You are user 1422, belonging to group 1420. Now you have full permissions.

Comment: @Aaron Gong I don't really know what the risk actually is. I guess it's unsafe, but the tech support is very slow...

Comment: The safe thing is to set the files to 644 and folders 755. This gives you the only right to change files and write into directories, but leaves everyone else permission to read. Apache is often run as another user, so you must giv it permission to read the files and directories.

Comment: @Daniel, check the php settings using ini_get()... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14784993/how-to-disable-all-file-uploads-to-a-server

Comment: Thank you. Php.ini is out of my reach unfortunately. (Or, since I seem to be no expert, fortunately instead.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1422 is the user_id the file belongs to and 1420 the group_id it belongs to.

Linux has a permission system, where you can give special permissions to the owner, your group and everyone else.

Permission 777 means everybody can read/write/execute, your group (1420) can read/write/execute and you (user 1422) can read/write/execute the file.

```
Permissions: 
1 is execute file or open directory 
2 is write 
4 is read
```

Read/write permission is 2+4=6, read/execute (or open a directory) is 1+4=5

The three numbers represents [owner][group][everybody], so setting a file to 644 means user can read/write and everybody else just read a file.

**Edit:** The safe thing is to set all files to 644 and directories to 755. Private files should be 600 and executable files 755 (PHP files are NOT executable).

Apache is run as user apache or httpd, which is another user, therefore you must give "everybody" permission to read your PHP files and directories.

**Edit2:** If you need PHP to upload files, it is really done as user apache/httpd. Therefore you need to give full privileges to "everybody" to open directories and read/write 777. The file permissions should be 666.

Comment: Thank you!! I've set files to 644, including the php file manager .php file, and folders to 755, and I still see "I/O error" when I try to upload files. php.ini is unaccessible for me. DirectAdmin works. Perhaps the only thing left is to wait for support answer?..

Comment: Can you get an explanation of the "I/O error", error writing, error logging in...

Comment: It's an error writing. The filemanager writes it that way when it can't write to a file.

Comment: How about using another ftp program, like Chrome or Firefox (`ftp://username:password@ftp.host.com/path`)

Comment: The problem is that I need my own PHP scripts to write files there... Ok! I see it's something I should contact the support for. Thanks to everybody :)

Comment: Create a directory with permission 777 and write your files into it from PHP. Uploading files through PHP, you really do it as user apache/httpd, so everybody needs read/write/execute permissions

Comment: It's strange, but creating directories and even copying files works, while uploads don't, even where 777 is written. Can't get it.