# Uploading a file via xampp

Tags: php, html

#'Hello there I wanted to upload a file with a html code and php code(In two files seperated). I followed the coding rules in my opinion, but when I upload a file it just brings me to my index.php side without even doing anything of my if conditional.
I tried multiple ways for hours now and it didn't work. Could anyone have a look please?(Link of the file C:\xampp\htdocs\mySite\uploads)

HTML CODE#

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>

<form action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Datei: <input type="file" name="hochladen" id="hochladen"/>
<input type="submit" value="Upload!!!" name="submit"/>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

PHP Code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>


<?php 
$ziel = "uploads/";
$zieldatei = $ziel . basename($_FILES["hochladen"]["name"]);
if(move_uploaded_file ($_FILES["hochladen"]["tmp_name"], $zieldatei )){
echo "File uploaded";}

else { echo "error";}
print_r ($_FILES);
var_dump ($_FILES);
echo $_FILES;
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `action="index.php"` means that the form will be posted to "index.php". If you want to post it to another page, change it to that file instead.

Comment: What error do you get. You can enable error reporting by adding `error_report(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", 1);` at the top of your php file

Comment: Have you disabled Php uploads. It is possible to disable Php uploads from php.ini configuration file. See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14785020/4508593. The file_uploads directive should be set to On

Comment: Well thats the thing. It doesn't matter whether I use Aavins Code from his Answer or my one with the error_report(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", 1);  There is literally no output at all on the page like the whole code wouldn't exist. Thanks for that Nadir the file_uploads= ON in my php.ini file. Could it be any other file as I don't think it's the Code alltogether?

Answer (score 0):

Guys I found the problem! Firstly thanks for all the answers I really appreciate that forum!
So the Problem was I had much PHP and HTML Code writen down over the upload Code in my filevand I used the  Code to cut all of it out. Even then the upper Code seems to prohibit some outputs of my upload code. Is there any save way to cut HTML + PHP Code out like a #comment ?

Answer (score -2):

This should help you

PHP Code

```
if(isset($_POST['editlogopic']))
{
    $logopic = ($_FILES['logopic']['name']);
    $logopicExt = end(explode('.', $logopic));
    $logopicExt = strtolower($logopicExt);

    if($logopic!="")
    {
        if($logopicExt != "png" && $logopicExt != "svg")
        {
            $file_upload="false";
            $errorMsg=$errorMsg."<div class='card-panel white-text red lighten-2 center-align'>Image file should be .png or .svg type</div>";
        }
    }

    if($errorMsg=='')
    {
        $targetlogopic = 'temp_name'.".".$logopicExt;

            $target_image_gallery_info = "../images/";
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['logopic']['tmp_name'],  $target_image_gallery_info.basename($targetlogopic));
            header('Location: info?ref=success');
    }
    else
    {
        $msg = '<div class="card-panel white-text red lighten-2 center-align">Background Image not Change!</div>';
    }
}
```

HTML Code

```
    <form method="post" class="col s12" action="service.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col s12">
                                Logo Image
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row valign-wrapper">
                            <div class="input-field col s12 m1 l1 center-align">
                                <img src="../images/<?php echo $row1['logopic']?>?<?php echo $dummy; ?>" class="circle materialboxed" width="50px" height="50px">
                            </div>
                            <div class="file-field input-field col s12 m9 l9">
                                <div class="btn">
                                    <span>Image</span>
                                    <input type="file" id="logopic" name="logopic">
                                </div>
                                <div class="file-path-wrapper">
                                    <input class="file-path" type="text" placeholder="Select .png or .svg photo only!">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="input-field col s12 m2 l2">
                                <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="editlogopic">Update
                                    <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Comment: 1. A good answer contains an _explanation_, not just code. 2. You might want to remove all extra fields and logic that the OP hasn't asked for. If anything, this "answer" will most likely confuse the OP even more + that this code has some issues on it's own.